# Python: Matrix multiplication error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I found two matrices (Mass and Stiffness) using the `scipy.sparse.diags` function and took one away from the other (Mass - Stiffness). When trying to multiply this new matrix by a vector `U0` I am getting the following

```
[ <6x6 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 16 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <6x6 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 16 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <6x6 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 16 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <6x6 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 16 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <6x6 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 16 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <6x6 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 16 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

I don't really understand this result - am I getting an 1D array of 6 matrices? If so, why am I getting this and not a simple vector?

The following is the code for creating the mass / stiffness matrix, finding `U0` and then the dot product

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy
from scipy.sparse import diags
import scipy.sparse.linalg
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def Mass_Matrix(x0):
    """Finds the Mass matrix for any non uniform mesh x0"""
    x0 = np.array(x0)
    N = len(x0) - 1
    h = x0[1:] - x0[:-1]
    a = np.zeros(N+1)
    a[0] = 1
    for j in range(1,N):
        a[j] = h[j-1]/3 + h[j]/3
    a[N] = 1
    b = h/6
    b[0] = 0
    c = h/6
    c[-1] = 0
    data = [a.tolist(), b.tolist(), c.tolist()]
    Positions = [0,1,-1]
    Mass_Matrix = diags(data, Positions, (N+1,N+1))

    return Mass_Matrix

def Poisson_Stiffness(x0):
    """Finds the Poisson equation stiffness matrix with any nonuniform mesh x0"""
    x0 = np.array(x0)
    N = len(x0) - 1 # The amount of elements; x0, x1, ..., xN
    h = x0[1:] - x0[:-1]
    a = np.zeros(N+1)
    a[0] = 1/h[0]
    a[1:-1] = 1/h[1:] + 1/h[:-1]
    a[-1] = 1/h[-1]
    a[N] = 1/h[N-1]
    b = -1/h
    c = -1/h
    data = [a.tolist(), b.tolist(), c.tolist()]
    Positions = [0, 1, -1]
    Stiffness_Matrix = diags(data, Positions, (N+1,N+1))

    return Stiffness_Matrix

def Nodal_Quadrature_f(x0):
    """Finds the Nodal Quadrature Approximation of sin(pi x)"""
    x0 = np.array(x0)
    h = x0[1:] - x0[:-1]
    N = len(x0) - 1
    approx = np.zeros(len(x0))
    for i in range(1,N):
        approx[i] = math.sin(math.pi*x0[i])
        approx[i] = (approx[i]*h[i-1] + approx[i]*h[i])/2

    return approx

def Initial_U(x0): 
    """Finds the initial U0"""
    x0 = np.array(x0)
    h = x0[1:] - x0[:-1]
    N = len(x0) - 1
    Mass = Mass_Matrix(x0)
    u0phi = Nodal_Quadrature_f(x0)
    U0 = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(Mass, u0phi)

    return U0

def timestepping(x0,theta,T,m):

    x0 = np.array(x0)
    h = x0[1:] - x0[:-1]
    N = len(x0) - 1
    dt = T/m
    U0 = np.array(Initial_U(x0))
    Mass = Mass_Matrix(x0)
    Stiffness = Poisson_Stiffness(x0)
    Iteration =  np.dot(Mass - Stiffness,U0)

    print Iteration
```

I will appreciate any help as I've been stuck on this for a few hours now.

EDIT: Some added information

the 6x6 matrix from the top is recieved after i call 
timestepping([0,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.9,1], 1, 1, 5)

i.e. x0 is just a partition of the doman 0 to 1. Theta, T and m are all irrelevant as i havent added it into the function yet.

Comment: Could you turn this into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by giving some example parameters (`x0, theta, T, m`)? It would also be helpful if you chained together the relevant function calls in a short script to make it easier to for others to replicate.

Comment: Hey, cheers for the reply. I have edited with my example parameters, but theta, T and m havent even been introduced into the problem yet as i realised i was getting this error before. x0 is just the domain [0,1] divided non-uniformly

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're seeing - I get  a vector of length `(6,)` for `Iteration`. Please could you edit your code to show all your import statements.

Comment: Done, that is now all of the code in my file

Comment: By the way, for me `np.dot(Mass - Stiffness,U0)` raises a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` For my versions of numpy (1.9.2) and scipy (0.15.1) `np.dot` doesn't properly support sparse arrays. That line can be replaced by `(Mass - Stiffness).dot(U0)` or `(Mass - Stiffness) * U0`, in which case I get a `(6,)` vector as I mentioned above.

Comment: Ahh that was it! Thank you SO much. Annoying i didnt realise that

Comment: You didn't mention *anything* about a `ValueError` in your question! If that was the problem then you should have said so, rather than wasting my time trying to replicate a totally different issue.

Comment: It didn't say Value error at all, the whole terminal output i pasted at the top of the screen. But i just changed it to the .dot(U) and it worked. Sorry anyway :)

Comment: Then either the code you're running differs from what's above, or there's some difference between your Python environment and mine, because I definitely can't reproduce the output you showed in your question.